# linq C# issue not getting expected output

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone tell me why this doesn't return anything? It's the `var temp =` part that's wrong: I'm not getting anything in there. The LINQ part: am I doing it wrong?

var temp = list.Select(x => x.Parent.Name == dir.Name).ToList();

Comment: `"why this doesn't return anything"` - Well, the `return` statement is empty.  So is the `catch` block, so it's essentially ignoring any and all errors.

Comment: You are trying to compare `DirectoryInfo` objects as if they were `integers`

Comment: Your OrderBy constructs an ordering query and then discards it.  This code has a lot of mistakes in it.  Asking why it doesn't work is a non-starter; there's no reason why it *should* work.

Comment: And why are you mixing fluent queries with query comprehensions? That's legal, but it looks weird.

Comment: Here's a good start at solving your problem: learn how to debug a small program. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: And why are you trying to implement a join with a subquery using where? If you're joining two sequences, just join them!

Comment: @BobKaufman, he's trying to compare the values of the DirectoryInfo objects but instead he is comparing the instances

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being *answered* and not *closed*!

Comment: @LuisLavieri: Of course you are right; you can't compare DirectoryInfos for equality; they will be referential, not value equality.

Comment: @DavidG: Of course this question should be closed. But let's remember that the high order bit here is being helpful. Sometimes the net most helpful thing you can do is close a question without answering it, but if there's some way to teach the original poster how to solve the problem or ask the question better, then it's reasonable to put some effort into it.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree mostly, but there's several reasons why helping here is, in my opinion, not worth it. The lack of effort taken to create the question, the lack of follow up (so far), the fact that blocks of code with "plz help" are explicitly off-topic here and answering them i highly discouraged. There's more but that's already more than enough. (PS your performance rant blog article is my most favourite link to post on SO!)

Comment: @DavidG: That's why I wrote it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first, it seems that you are using this code within a `void` method. You should redesign the method to return an empty `DirectoryInfo` list. But, putting a `return` statement within a loop that is checking directories does not seem right.

Second, you are using two different `Linq` approaches, and when you call the `OrderBy()`, you are not assigning it to anything.

So, at the end. Your query should look like something similar to this. However, I would try to redesign the method first. Notice that I am using the full name of the path. Because that way you compare the values of the object instead of the instances.

```
var temp = list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Parent.FullName.Equals(dir.FullName))
               .OrderBy(i => i.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm finding it really hard to understand this code in isolation, but I think the logic you are attempting to express is:

```
var q = from dir in parent
        where IsMainBranch(dir) 
        where parents.Contains(dir)
        join sdir in list on dir equals sdir.Parent 
        orderby sdir.Name 
        select sdir;
list2.AddRange(q);
return list2;
```

Is that right? If so, then maybe either write the code as a bunch of nested loops, *or* as a query, but not *both at the same time*.

Note that **you cannot compare DirectoryInfo for equality**:

```
    var a = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
    var b = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
    Console.WriteLine(a == b); // False!
```

Directory *infos* are not *directories*. I suggest that you modify your code so that the collections are collections of canonical directory names.